# apt-get update doesn't work after installation in kali rolling 2016

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade, repository

I have installed `kali-linux rolling 2016.1` recently and the output of `uname -a` is

```
Linux kali 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5kali4 (2016-01-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After installation I updated my sources.list file according to latest repositories available

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

After running apt-get update command I am unable to update packages list, its simply not working by displaying output

```
root@kali:~# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Release
Ign:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en_US
Ign:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Ign:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:11 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Ign:13 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en_US
Ign:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Ign:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:11 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Ign:13 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en_US
Ign:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Ign:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:11 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Ign:13 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en_US
Ign:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Ign:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:11 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Ign:13 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign:14 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
  400  Bad Request
Ign:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en_US
Ign:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Err:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
  400  Bad Request
Ign:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Ign:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:10 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Err:11 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
  400  Bad Request
Ign:12 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Ign:13 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages  400  Bad Request
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  400  Bad Request
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  400  Bad Request
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I think there is some issue with apt-get packages as I am able to access Internet via browser and curl is working fine as well. 
I followed the following link  [here](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?32372-apt-get-cannot-update-after-fresh-install) to reinstall apt packages but these `.deb` files are either has already updated or have become deprecated as they are not on this link anymore.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem I faced was my WIFI, I am not sure either its strength or outgoing,i incoming constraints. I started using LAN which was in different network and all works fine. Thanks everyone for trying help.